# Finding the max values of lists in dictionaries - python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary whose key is an integer, and whose value is a list. I'd like to return a new dictionary with the top n dictionary entries with the lowest values of `list[0]`.

For example, if I have a dictionary like this

```
{1: [5, 'hello'], 2: [6, 'hi'], 3: [2, 'hey']}
```

and n is 2, it would return

```
{1: [5, 'hello'], 3: [2, 'hey']}
```

Comment: did you make any attempt at it yourself?

Comment: Yes, I'm just wondering if there is a smarter way to do it, perhaps using some of that cool python shorthand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
from heapq import nsmallest
from operator import itemgetter

d = {1: [5, 'hello'], 2:[6, 'hi'], 3:[2,'hey']} 

smallestN = dict(nsmallest(2, d.items(), itemgetter(1)))

print(smallestN)
```

You can also do it without importing `heapq` or `itemgetter`:

```
smallestN = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][0])[:2])
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you :)